# Why is my Dialog dismissed before finishing?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

In my fragment, I want to show a dialog to insert some data before calling another function and moving to another activity, but the dialog keeps being automatically dismissed and the next line of code after dialog.show() is being called whether I finish the dialog or not.
here is the code for my dialog:

```
package com.technion.doggyguide;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import com.technion.doggyguide.R;


import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class GoogleSignInDialog extends DialogFragment {
private static final String TAG = "GOOGLE DIALOG";

public interface OnInputListener {
    void sendInput(String dogname, String dogbreed);
}

public OnInputListener mOnInputListener;

private EditText mDogName, mDogBreed;
private TextView mSet, mCancel;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_google_sign_in, container, false);
    mDogBreed = view.findViewById(R.id.input_breed);
    mDogName = view.findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    mSet = view.findViewById(R.id.action_ok);
    mCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.action_cancel);

    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    mSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String dogname = mDogName.getText().toString();
            String dogbreed = mDogBreed.getText().toString();
            if (dogname.isEmpty() || dogbreed.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "Please enter the name and breed of your dog" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            mOnInputListener.sendInput(dogname, dogbreed);
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mOnInputListener = (OnInputListener) getTargetFragment();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

and here is the code for my fragment:

```
private void signIWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    Log.d("TAG", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    final CollectionReference dogowners = db.collection("dog owners");
    dogowners.whereEqualTo("email", account.getEmail())
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = task.getResult().getDocuments();
                    if (docs.isEmpty()) {
                        GoogleSignInDialog dialog = new GoogleSignInDialog();
                        dialog.setTargetFragment(DogOwnerConnectionFragment.this, 1);
                        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyCustomDialog");
                        firstGoogleSignIn(credential, account);
                    } else if (docs.size() == 1) {
                        GoogleSignIn(credential, account);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

the real question is how do I stop the code from running before I finish the dialog?

Comment: Sounds to me like start ActivityForResult is what you're looking for, like a FAB.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 0):

First: Let Your Fragment implement OnInputListener and override function

Second: setListener after you create the dialog

```
GoogleSignInDialog dialog = new GoogleSignInDialog();
dialog.setListener(this);
.
.
```

GoogleSignInDialog

```
void setListener(OnInputListener listener){

    mOnInputListener = listener;
}
```

then you can use this interface to callback to fragment and do something before you dismiss the dialog

```
mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        listener.doSomething()//do anything you want

        getDialog().dismiss();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is that android designed dialogs to be asynchronous, so a you cannot possibly freeze the code while the dialog is opened and since the next called function starts another activity, the context is changed, hence the crash.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, I did what you show and didn't help. Is there any other possible way to stop the main thread from running while on dialog ?

Comment: @asselqi what is crash log